# ExtJs - best way to check if Ext.Array is empty?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

In ExtJS, using an Ext.Array (after using `Ext.Array.difference`), I get a resulting array and would like to know the best way to check if the array is empty?

I did use `theArray.length` as one could do in javascript, but I'm wondering if there is a better way/faster to acheive that? (At first I thought that `isEmpty` would help but it seems to be working on object, not array)

Comment: `Ext.isEmpty` handles empty arrays, `Ext.isEmpty([])` `>true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily add this to the Array prototype like this:

```
Array.prototype.isEmpty = function(){
    return !this.length;
};
var a = ['a','b','c','d'];
var b = ['b','d','f','h'];
var c = Ext.Array.difference(a,b);
var d = [];
console.log(c.isEmpty(), d.isEmpty());
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks!  This is good to know. (can't vote up youre answer yet, but I would if I could)

Comment: I would recommend against doing this because putting methods native object prototypes is harder to maintain and makes it more difficult to play nice with other libraries.

Comment: He could add it to the Ext.Array class doing         `Ext.apply(Ext.Array,{isEmpty : function (array) {return !array.length;}});` and using it like `Ext.Array.isEmpty(c);` but I think that for most projects adding a simple method to the Array prototype wouldnt hurt that much ;)